# distributed lock 'balancer/server1.test.com:40000:1367458475:1804289383' unlocked

Tags: mongodb

I used two pc to db server, where the mongodb version is 2.4.1, and the system architecture is as follows:

**process list for server1.test.com(192.168.156.39):**

```
./mongodb/mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard1 --rest --port 27017 --dbpath ./mongodata/data --oplogSize 5000 --logpath ./mongodata/logs/shard1.log --logappend --fork
./mongodb/mongod --configsvr --port 30000 --dbpath ./mongodata/config --logpath ./mongodata/logs/config.log --logappend --fork
./mongodb/mongos --configdb server1.test.com:30000 --port 40000 --chunkSize 5 --logpath ./mongodata/logs/mongos.log --logappend --fork
```

**process list for server2.test.com(192.168.156.40):**

```
./mongodb/mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard1 --rest --port 27017 --dbpath ./mongodata/data --oplogSize 5000 --logpath ./mongodata/logs/shard1.log --logappend --fork
./mongodb/mongos --configdb server1.test.com:30000 --port 40000 --chunkSize 5 --logpath ./mongodata/logs/mongos.log --logappend --fork
```

**the shard list:**

```
mongos> sh.status()
--- Sharding Status ---
sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "version" : 3,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 3,
    "currentVersion" : 4,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("5170a7faa5daa853bde9fe11")
}
shards:
    {  "_id" : "s1",  "host" : "shard1/server1.test.com:27017,server2.test.com:27017" }
databases:
    {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
    {  "_id" : "crawler",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "s1" }
```

That were running a few days as normal, but suddenly, all processes auto-exited except `mongod`. I checked the logs, which show the following:

**server1 - shard1.log**

```
Thu May  2 10:34:24.653 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.156.40:45113 #37770 (22 connections now open)
Thu May  2 10:34:36.748 [conn37623] command admin.$cmd command: { writebacklisten: ObjectId('5181c2ab7c46e60e12ace47b') } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:44 300000ms
Thu May  2 10:34:54.666 [conn37770] end connection 192.168.156.40:45113 (20 connections now open)
Thu May  2 10:34:54.667 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.156.40:45114 #37773 (22 connections now open)
Thu May  2 10:35:24.680 [conn37773] end connection 192.168.156.40:45114 (20 connections now open)
Thu May  2 10:35:24.681 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.156.40:45115 #37774 (22 connections now open)
Thu May  2 10:35:54.694 [conn37774] end connection 192.168.156.40:45115 (20 connections now open)
Thu May  2 10:35:54.694 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.156.40:45116 #37775 (22 connections now open)
```

**server1 - config.log**

```
Thu May  2 09:35:23.642 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.156.40:43971 #5 (5 connections now open)
Thu May  2 09:35:23.658 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.156.40:43978 #6 (6 connections now open)
Thu May  2 09:35:47.842 [conn1] update config.mongos query: { _id: "server1.test.com:40000" } update: { $set: { ping: new Date(1367458547741), up: 72, waiting: false, mongoVersion: "2.4.1" } } idhack:1 nupdated:1 fastmod:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:46 101ms
Thu May  2 09:41:54.226 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.156.40:43992 #7 (7 connections now open)
Thu May  2 10:28:08.830 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.156.39:55161 #8 (8 connections now open)
Thu May  2 10:28:08.831 [conn8] first cluster operation detected, adding sharding hook to enable versioning and authentication to remote servers
Thu May  2 10:29:35.218 [conn5] update config.locks query: { _id: "balancer", state: 0, ts: ObjectId('5181cf8c7c46e60e12ace6a1') } update: { $set: { state: 1, who: "server2.test.com:40000:1367458523:1804289383:Balancer:846930886", process: "server2.test.com:40000:1367458523:1804289383", when: new Date(1367461775087), why: "doing balance round", ts: ObjectId('5181cf8f5cc22604fbfdb9dd') } } nscanned:1 nupdated:1 fastmod:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:238 120ms
```

**server1 - mongos.log**

```
Thu May  2 10:41:03.659 [Balancer] distributed lock 'balancer/server1.test.com:40000:1367458475:1804289383' acquired, ts : 5181d23f7c46e60e12ace714
Thu May  2 10:41:03.661 [Balancer] distributed lock 'balancer/server1.test.com:40000:1367458475:1804289383' unlocked.
Thu May  2 10:41:09.665 [Balancer] distributed lock 'balancer/server1.test.com:40000:1367458475:1804289383' acquired, ts : 5181d2457c46e60e12ace715
Thu May  2 10:41:09.667 [Balancer] distributed lock 'balancer/server1.test.com:40000:1367458475:1804289383' unlocked.
Thu May  2 10:41:15.671 [Balancer] distributed lock 'balancer/server1.test.com:40000:1367458475:1804289383' acquired, ts : 5181d24b7c46e60e12ace716
Thu May  2 10:41:15.674 [Balancer] distributed lock 'balancer/server1.test.com:40000:1367458475:1804289383' unlocked.
```

**server2 - shard1.log**

```
Thu May  2 10:49:19.122 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.156.39:56166 #37872 (17 connections now open)
Thu May  2 10:49:36.763 [conn37634] command admin.$cmd command: { writebacklisten: ObjectId('5181c2ab7c46e60e12ace47b') } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:44 300000ms
Thu May  2 10:49:38.725 [conn37635] info DFM::findAll(): extent 0:3db000 was empty, skipping ahead. ns:crawler.crawl_js_url_queue
Thu May  2 10:49:49.138 [conn37872] end connection 192.168.156.39:56166 (15 connections now open)
Thu May  2 10:49:49.139 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.156.39:56167 #37873 (17 connections now open)
Thu May  2 10:50:17.666 [conn37635] info DFM::findAll(): extent 0:3db000 was empty, skipping ahead. ns:crawler.crawl_js_url_queue
Thu May  2 10:50:19.153 [conn37873] end connection 192.168.156.39:56167 (15 connections now open)
Thu May  2 10:50:19.154 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.156.39:56170 #37874 (17 connections now open)
```

**server2 - mongs.log**

```
Thu May  2 10:56:42.921 [Balancer] distributed lock 'balancer/server2.test.com:40000:1367463294:1804289383' unlocked.
Thu May  2 10:56:48.926 [Balancer] distributed lock 'balancer/server2.test.com:40000:1367463294:1804289383' acquired, ts : 5181d5f0df728e935d741181
Thu May  2 10:56:48.929 [Balancer] distributed lock 'balancer/server2.test.com:40000:1367463294:1804289383' unlocked.
Thu May  2 10:56:54.934 [Balancer] distributed lock 'balancer/server2.test.com:40000:1367463294:1804289383' acquired, ts : 5181d5f6df728e935d741182
Thu May  2 10:56:54.937 [Balancer] distributed lock 'balancer/server2.test.com:40000:1367463294:1804289383' unlocked.
Thu May  2 10:57:00.944 [Balancer] distributed lock 'balancer/server2.test.com:40000:1367463294:1804289383' acquired, ts : 5181d5fcdf728e935d741183
Thu May  2 10:57:00.947 [Balancer] distributed lock 'balancer/server2.test.com:40000:1367463294:1804289383' unlocked.
Thu May  2 10:57:06.952 [Balancer] distributed lock 'balancer/server2.test.com:40000:1367463294:1804289383' acquired, ts : 5181d602df728e935d741184
```

If I delete data on server2, then sync data from server1, maybe it's ok, but the data has differences between the two servers, so I cann't do this. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: What exactly makes you think the data is different on the two shards? All of the logs look normal to me. Which processes died?  The mongos?  The config servers? both?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stackoverflow, Jerry. FYI, with output like this from a log, it's often easier to save it in a [gist](http://gist.github.com) and link to it. If you want to include it directly in your question, you should put four spaces in front of each line of log -- that forces it to be treated literally (like code). You also don't need <br/> tags.

Comment: 1)"What exactly makes you think the data is different on the two shards?",I running command 'du -h' on the two server,then the storage size is different.2)Yes,the both were died."./mongodb/mongod --shardsvr " is active only.

Comment: Hi mohawkjohn,thank you for reminding.

Comment: You can also comment code using backticks: `code`, which are not the same as single quotes 'code'. On an English keyboard, backtick is located on the same key as `~`.

Comment: The fact that the two servers have allocated different size files does not mean the data is different.  Have you restarted the `mongos` and config servers?  If not I would and get another `sh.status()` to post.

Comment: Oh,I understand.I have to restart all processes, the Server2 state has been  "syncing to: server1.test.com:27017",and no change log.

Comment: I think you are up and running.  Can you post rs.status() from server1:27017 and server2:27017?

Comment: Oh,my god,the server1 state is "was DOWN".

Comment: That is why you run a replica set!  Just start it again an it should re-sync with server 2.

Comment: More strange things happened, and I cann't kill on server1 "./ Mongodb / mongod - shardsvr" process.Its status becomes "[mongod] <defunct>,".

Comment: That is not good.  Check the parent pid of the defunct process if it is 1 then about the only fix is to reboot the machine.  If the parent pid is a script try killing the script to clean up the defunct process. FYI - when I have had mongod processes become zombies (defunct) in the past for me it turned out to be either a bad memory DIMM or a bad harddrive. (We had a bunch of blades with a bad batch of DIMMs and had a lot of zombies for a while. Not a fun time.)

Comment: Ha ha~OK,I'll told to system dept checked it,thanks so much.

Comment: Sometimes, I really want to give up the use MongoDB in the project.Because it is always some problems.

Comment: Reboot server 1,after that I deleted data on the server 2,restart all process(shardsvr,configsvr,mongos) on the two server,then the server 2 sync data from server 1,the replset restore normal.